# EWS: Same public folder has different UniqueIDs per user?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am experiencing a strange problem: When I look to the very same folder (on a Public Folder on an Exchange 2010) I get two different UniqueIDs for two different users:

It seems the Ids contain both user-specific parts and common parts. How can I identify them as the same folder?

Edit: On some systems the FolderID.UniqueID of a folder is the same for all users.

Comment: what do you mean by how can I identify them as the same folder? So 1 GUID for 1 Folder for Both Users?

Comment: Exactly. Both IDs are representations for the same folder (e.g. Public Folder/Myfolders/Folder1). So the path itself would be an unique ID but its not invariant due to renaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the PR_SOURCE_KEY Extended property instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178895(v=exchg.80).aspx this will always be consistent on public folders and you can also use that property in MAPI to access the folder in an Outlook Plugin

Cheers
Glen

Answer (score 1):

This is Actually a very common problem faced by those who are using the EWS Managed API.

For some reason (I do not know why) the Unique ID changes when the appointment is moved to another folder.

So what you could try is set an `ExtendesPropertyDefinition` where you declare your **GUID / UniqueID** for the Folder you are working on, and everytime you do `folder.update` or `appointment.update` (if it's an appointment) you can pass your `extendedPropertyDefinition` to that `update()` method.

Just use this code below with your folders (replace appointment with folders and that should work somehow :))

private static readonly PropertyDefinitionBase AppointementIdPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "AppointmentID", MapiPropertyType.String);

```
public static PropertySet PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, AppointementIdPropertyDefinition);


//Setting the property for the appointment 
 public static void SetGuidForAppointement(Appointment appointment)
{
    try
    {
        appointment.SetExtendedProperty((ExtendedPropertyDefinition)AppointementIdPropertyDefinition, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // logging the exception
    }
}

//Getting the property for the appointment
 public static string GetGuidForAppointement(Appointment appointment)
{
    var result = "";
    try
    {
        appointment.Load(PropertySet);
        foreach (var extendedProperty in appointment.ExtendedProperties)
        {
            if (extendedProperty.PropertyDefinition.Name == "AppointmentID")
            {
                result = extendedProperty.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     // logging the exception
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: adding data to the imtes is not an option, but thanks for your help.